# How we retrieve all groups and user from Active directory using client side code in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api

I am not getting domain groups /security groups or groups created in azure using rest Api.
Is there any other method or approach to check users from groups in Active directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query Graph API to get the information from Azure active directory. If you want to build a solution using Javascript (script editor etc), you can use the [ADAL for javascript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) for authentication and fetching the required data from Graph.

If you are building a SharePoint framework solution, here is a good reference of [calling Azure AD secured APIs from SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)

Here is a good series on how to call the Graph API with Adal.js : https://julieturner.net/2017/01/extending-sharepoint-with-adal-and-the-microsoft-graph-api-part-2-the-authorization/

Comment: Can I use this Microsoft Graph without node js or npm (simply using javascript)?

Comment: Updated the answer with a reference to a blog series on using Adal.js to call graph API